# What is a Predicate Delegate and where should it be used?

Tags: c#, .net, predicate

Can you explain to me:

- What is a Predicate Delegate?
- Where should we use predicates?
- Any best practices when using predicates?

Descriptive source code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

A predicate is a function that returns `true` or `false`.  A predicate delegate is a reference to a predicate.

So basically a predicate delegate is a reference to a function that returns `true` or `false`.  Predicates are very useful for filtering a list of values - here is an example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

        Predicate<int> predicate = new Predicate<int>(greaterThanTwo);

        List<int> newList = list.FindAll(predicate);
    }

    static bool greaterThanTwo(int arg)
    {
        return arg > 2;
    }
}
```

Now if you are using C# 3 you can use a lambda to represent the predicate in a cleaner fashion:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

        List<int> newList = list.FindAll(i => i > 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Hare: in your first code snippet, should that be `yeild return` instead? Or how does that work, how does it iterate over the whole list?

Comment: @VoodooChild: Remember that the predicate will be called for each element in the sequence *in turn*. So `greaterThanTwo` has `return` not `yield return` since it is the `FindAll` method that is handling the sequence for you.

Answer (score 81):

Leading on from Andrew's answer with regards to c#2 and c#3 ... you can also do them inline for a one off search function (see below).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

        List<int> newList = list.FindAll(delegate(int arg)
                           {
                               return arg> 2;
                           });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

Just a delegate that returns a boolean.  It is used a lot in filtering lists but can be used wherever you'd like.

```
List<DateRangeClass>  myList = new List<DateRangeClass<GetSomeDateRangeArrayToPopulate);
myList.FindAll(x => (x.StartTime <= minDateToReturn && x.EndTime >= maxDateToReturn):
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a good article on predicates [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120420194059/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163550.aspx), although it's from the .NET2 era, so there's no mention of lambda expressions in there.

Answer (score 7):

**What is Predicate Delegate?**

1) Predicate is a feature that returns true or false.This concept has come in .net 2.0 framework. 
2) It is being used with lambda expression (=>). It takes generic type as an argument.
3) It allows a predicate function to be defined and passed as a parameter to another function.
4) It is a special case of a `Func`, in that it takes only a single parameter and always returns a bool.

In C# namespace:

```
namespace System
{   
    public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj);
}
```

It is defined in the System namespace.

**Where should we use Predicate Delegate?**

We should use Predicate Delegate in the following cases:

1) For searching items in a generic collection.
  e.g.

```
var employeeDetails = employees.Where(o=>o.employeeId == 1237).FirstOrDefault();
```

2) Basic example that shortens the code and returns true or false:

```
Predicate<int> isValueOne = x => x == 1;
```

now, Call above predicate:

```
Console.WriteLine(isValueOne.Invoke(1)); // -- returns true.
```

3) An anonymous method can also be assigned to a Predicate delegate type as below:

```
Predicate<string> isUpper = delegate(string s) { return s.Equals(s.ToUpper());};
    bool result = isUpper("Hello Chap!!");
```

**Any best practices about predicates?**

Use Func, Lambda Expressions and Delegates instead of Predicates.

Answer (score 5):

The predicate-based searching methods allow a method delegate or lambda expression to decide whether a given element is a “match.”
 A predicate is simply a delegate accepting an object and returning true or false:
public delegate bool Predicate (T object);

```
   static void Main()
        {
            string[] names = { "Lukasz", "Darek", "Milosz" };
            string match1 = Array.Find(names, delegate(string name) { return name.Contains("L"); });
            //or
            string match2 = Array.Find(names, delegate(string name) { return name.Contains("L"); });
            //or
            string match3 = Array.Find(names, x => x.Contains("L"));


            Console.WriteLine(match1 + " " + match2 + " " + match3);     // Lukasz Lukasz Lukasz
        }
        static bool ContainsL(string name) { return name.Contains("L"); }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're in VB 9 (VS2008), a predicate can be a complex function:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1, 2, 3})
Dim newList = list.FindAll(AddressOf GreaterThanTwo)
...
Function GreaterThanTwo(ByVal item As Integer) As Boolean
    'do some work'
    Return item > 2
End Function
```

Or you can write your predicate as a lambda, as long as it's only one expression:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {1, 2, 3})
Dim newList = list.FindAll(Function(item) item > 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Predicate falls under the category of generic delegates in C#. This is called with one argument and always return the boolean type. Basically, the predicate is used to test the condition - true/false. Many classes support predicate as an argument. For example, list.findall expects the parameter predicate. Here is an example of predicate.

Imagine a function pointer with the signature:

```
<modifier> bool delegate myDelegate<in T>(T match);
```

Here is the example:

Node.cs:

```
namespace PredicateExample
{
    class Node
    {
        public string Ip_Address { get; set; }
        public string Node_Name { get; set; }
        public uint Node_Area { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PredicateExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Predicate<Node> backboneArea = Node =>  Node.Node_Area == 0 ;
            List<Node> Nodes = new List<Node>();
            Nodes.Add(new Node { Ip_Address = "1.1.1.1", Node_Area = 0, Node_Name = "Node1" });
            Nodes.Add(new Node { Ip_Address = "2.2.2.2", Node_Area = 1, Node_Name = "Node2" });
            Nodes.Add(new Node { Ip_Address = "3.3.3.3", Node_Area = 2, Node_Name = "Node3" });
            Nodes.Add(new Node { Ip_Address = "4.4.4.4", Node_Area = 0, Node_Name = "Node4" });
            Nodes.Add(new Node { Ip_Address = "5.5.5.5", Node_Area = 1, Node_Name = "Node5" });
            Nodes.Add(new Node { Ip_Address = "6.6.6.6", Node_Area = 0, Node_Name = "Node6" });
            Nodes.Add(new Node { Ip_Address = "7.7.7.7", Node_Area = 2, Node_Name = "Node7" });

            foreach( var item in Nodes.FindAll(backboneArea))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Node Name " + item.Node_Name + " Node IP Address " + item.Ip_Address);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply -> they provide True/False values based on condition mostly used for querying.
mostly used with delegates

consider example of list

```
List<Program> blabla= new List<Program>();
        blabla.Add(new Program("shubham", 1));
        blabla.Add(new Program("google", 3));
        blabla.Add(new Program("world",5));
        blabla.Add(new Program("hello", 5));
        blabla.Add(new Program("bye", 2));
```

contains names and ages. 
Now say we want to find names on condition
So I Will use,

```
    Predicate<Program> test = delegate (Program p) { return p.age > 3; };
        List<Program> matches = blabla.FindAll(test);
        Action<Program> print = Console.WriteLine;
        matches.ForEach(print);
```

tried to Keep it Simple!