# C# writing a type signature for `WhereWithIndex`

Tags: c#, generics, collections, functional-programming, extension-methods

After seeing an answer that specified how to enumerate the indexes using of a collection using Linq, I decided to write an extension method `WhereWithIndex` that behaves simlarly to `Where`, but the input function should have two arguments, the item and the index.

Example usage should be:

```
names = new String[] {"Bob", "Alice", "Luke", "Carol"}
names.WhereWithIndex( (_, index) => index % 2 == 0 ) // -> {"Bob", "Luke"}
```

I have been able to inline this logic into my program, it looks like this:

```
iterable
  .Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
  .Where(x => condition(item, index))
  .Select(x => x.item);
```

But the type signature I should give to this extension method still eludes me. I tried:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WhereWithIndex(this IEnumerable<T> iterable, Predicate<T, int> condition) {
```

Because I want as input an enumerable of anything I could not mark it with `int` or `String` so I tried using `T` to signify generality [following the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx), the condition is a predicate so I stated so. How to express the type of a delegate with 2 arguments further eludes me, I tried using a comma to separate the arguments, but I am just guessing as [I could only fund examples of predicates with only one input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556425/predicate-delegates-in-c-sharp).

It gives me the error:

```
Example.cs(22,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `T' could     
not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Any idea on writing this type signature? If it is simpler in C# version 6 it would be nice to mention it too.

Comment: btw, `Where` has an overload with index: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx; regarding your problem: make a generic method : `WhereWithIndex<T>` if you still need it

Comment: You've missed `T` after method name: `... WhereWithIndex<T>(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There [already exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) a version of `Where` that does that. It has this signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate);
```

The only thing your signature was missing was the `<TSource>` next to `Where`. That tells the compiler the function is a generic. Plus using `Func<TSource, int, bool>` instead of `Predicate<T, int>`. In C#, `Func<P1, P2, P3, R>` is a function that takes P1, P2, P3 and returns R, such as:

```
public R MyFunction(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3) { ... }
```

On the other hand, an `Action<P1, P2>` is a function that take P1 and P2 and does not return anything:

```
public void MyAction(P1 p1, P2 p2) { ... }
```

Note that in these samples, `MyFunction` and `MyAction` are not generics (P1..P3 and R would need to be actual types). If you'd like to make it generic, you'd change it to:

```
public void MyAction<P1, P2>(P1 p1, P2 p2) { ... }
```

In this case, P1 and P2 are arbitrary type variable names.

Comment: Why do you use `TSource` over `T` ?

Comment: And why `Function` with return type `bool` instead of `Predicate`? Is this a newly added feature?

Comment: That's just an arbitrary type variable name that represents the type of the `IEnumerable`. It could be anything.

Comment: Is not, I think you're confusing it with Java. In C#, Func<A, B, C, .... Z> is a function that takes A, B, C... and returns Z. So Func<TSource, int, bool> takes a TSource and an int and returns a boolean.

Comment: I get the distinction between `Func` and `Action`, but the compiler should handle this automatically when I write an anonymous function right? Like `(x => System.Console.WriteLine(x))` is an `Action` and `(x => x + 1)` is a `Func`

Comment: That's right. The syntax I used is for non-anonymous functions, just to make it clearer. Normally you want to use anonymous ones.