# Find() In a System.Collections.Generic.List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am using a Telerik OrgChart control. I’m basically struggling to extract rendered field from a node.  You can add **OrgChartRenderedField** to each node; this has a property called Label.

Each **OrgChartRenderedField** per node is contained within an **OrgChartRenderedFieldCollection**

```
public class OrgChartRenderedFieldCollection : System.Collections.Generic.List<OrgChartRenderedField>
Member of Telerik.Web.UI
```

It has a method called find()

```
public T Find(System.Predicate<T> match)
Member of System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
```

Summary:
Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire System.Collections.Generic.List.

Parameters:
match: The System.Predicate delegate that defines the conditions of the element to search for.

Returns:
The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T.

Exceptions:
System.ArgumentNullException: match is null.

The main problem I have is that I can’t figure out how to search the collection for specific OrgChartRenderedField object where the Label = ‘Some text’
Appreciate it’s a third party plugin; hoping knowing the types of objects somebody can give me a suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: That method is part of `List<T>`, it should be as simple as `list.Find(o => o.Label == "Some Text")`

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/556442/4416750) for an explanation of a predicate delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) method is part of `List<T>`. The usage requires a delegate, the simplest way is probably to use a lambda, something like this:

```
var item = list.Find(o => o.Label == "Some Text");
```