# Is there an analog IntPredicate in C#?

Tags: c#, predicate

In Java I can import `java.util.function.IntPredicate;` and use a ready-made solution for example

```
public boolean satisfies(IntPredicate p) {
        return p.test(getChar());
}
```

```
satisfies(Character::isWhitespace);
```

Does something similar exist in C# ?

Comment: Can you explain what your code does?

Comment: You mean something like `Func<int, bool>`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I would say something like `Predicate<T>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netcore-3.1 ?

Comment: You may get from here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/556442/12387766

Comment: You should use `Func<int, bool>. `There is also `Predicate<int>` but that is only used in some legacy code.

Comment: @John I am doing lexical analysis of the language. And I want to skip some characters, in this case whitespace. But I would like to write something more universal, so as not to write its code for each individual character